# Distinguish the meaning of the word "word"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

As I know, the word *word* can be understood as

1. <s>vocabulary</s> unit of meaning

> A single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically shown with a space on either side when written or printed.

2. statement / sentence

> Something spoken or written; a remark or statement.

What make me confused is that how can I distinguish these two different meanings in case like this one:

```
A friendly waiter taught me a few words of Italian.
```

Is it

1. He taught me a few vocabularies of Italian.
   or
2. He taught me a few sentences/statements of Italian.

Comment: I searched with the words in your first definition, and nothing included the word "vocabulary". Did you add that yourself? It's incorrect

Comment: @gotube Yes, the "vocabulary" is my understanding, the quoted explanation below is from a dictionary exactly. I would have meant that a single word in vocabulary.

Comment: To answer your question then, it could mean either individual words or some phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "A friendly waiter taught me a few words of Italian."

In the strict interpretation, "words" in this sentence indicates that the friendly waiter gave you a few individual words -- i.e. individual units of meaning.  For example, the waiter taught you "bella" and told you that it meant pretty or beautiful.

But, in actual usage, "a few words" can also indicate a phrase or a sentence such as "una ragazza bella" (a beautiful girl) because -- well -- a phrase is composed of a few words.

Comment: You just added a third possibility. So it can be understood as **1.** _a few individual words_; **2.** _a sentence (formed by a few individual words)_; **3.** _a few sentences_.

Answer (score 1):

I think things would be clearer with a slightly modified definition of the word 'vocabulary' as 'a collection of words'.

Some ways I would use the word 'vocabulary' in a sentence:

- "I was impressed at the size of my friend's vocabulary"
- "This text is challenging to read because the author uses a diverse vocabulary"

With this definition hopefully it becomes a bit more clear that sentence #2 is the more correct one. To modify #1 I would say : "He extended my Italian vocabulary"

Comment: Thanks for your replay. See the comment above, I misunderstood the meaning of vocabulary. Please refer to the quoted part below "1. vocabulary". So, if I see the sentence "A friendly waiter taught me a few words of Italian.", can I consider it as the meaning of "He extended my Italian vocabulary". Or to be more clearly, "He taught me a few words (in term of vocabulary) of Italian.

Comment: May be I should say "unit of meaning" instead of "vocabulary". I don't know how to express the meaning of "word" using another word, sorry.

Comment: "A friendly waiter taught me a few words of Italian.", can I consider it as the meaning of "He extended my Italian vocabulary" -> this captures the difference well. 'word' is singular, whereas 'vocabulary' is plural. A collection of many words creates a vocabulary. For this reason we would rarely use the word 'vocabularies' because this is a plural of a plural. A use of 'vocabularies' may be 'all my students have great vocabularies'